# Why won't my jQuery UI dialog show up when it's div is nested?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, dialog

I'm trying to show a dialog (div) that's inside another div. This way, I can easily keep all my dialogs together.

The page looks something like this:

```
<div id="bookshelf">
    <div id="login">dialog</div>
</div>
```

I've added the needed properties to it:

```
$("div#bookshelf div#login").dialog({ autoOpen: false });
```

and try to make it show up:

```
$("div#bookshelf div#login").dialog("open");
```

and it won't.

However, if I change the last line to

```
$("div#login").dialog("open");
```

It does! But I don't want to refer to it directly, because propably something else on my page will be called "login" as well, at some point. And I wanted to stop making those very long id's like id="lp_dialogs_bookshelf_login".

Am I doing something wrong here? Or should I just forget about it, and start using those nasty id's again?

Comment: Nothing else on the page should have an `id` of "login". The whole point of the `id` attribute is that it represents one and only one element on the page.

Comment: Agreed. You should use `class` attributes instead of `id`s.

Comment: You are right, but it just "felt" so wrong to use those long id's. I will start doing that however, and reference the dialog directly. Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you created the dialog, it moved this:

```
<div id="login">dialog</div>
```

To the end of your html document, just before `</body>`, so the selector `$("div#bookshelf div#login")` doesn't find it...because it isn't inside there anymore.

I would just use `div#login` in all cases since it should be unique, but to make your example work, you need to move the dialog after it's created, like this:

```
$("div#bookshelf div#login").dialog({ autoOpen: false })
                            .parent().appendTo('#bookself');
```

Comment: I'll give the dialog a different, longer id, and will reference it directly, but it's great to learn exactly why it didn't work! Thank you very much!